# didSelectRowAtIndexPath display in UIWebView

Tags: ios, parsing, uitableview, webview, feed

I'm using `MWFeedParser`, and I want a tap on a cell to open up a webview rather than another `UITableViewController`.  This is what happens at didSelect...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Show detail
DetailTableViewController *detail = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
detail.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];


// Deselect
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

I think my first obstacle is obtaining the URL from each RSS post so that the webview knows what to display.  How is this done, and how would I go about changing the above method to open a webview?

Changed to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

webViewController *webView = [[webViewController alloc] initWithURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
webView.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];


[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

But initWithURL is giving me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the base class of `webViewController` and I suspect it does not contain the method `initWithURL`. (btw, `webViewController`, if it is a class, is not following the recommended naming convention either - class names should start with a capital letter, and variables/instance methods start with lower case - check out Apple's guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1))

Also, `@"http://www.google.com"`  is not a URL - it's a string. To create a URL object, you need to do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Then use the `url` object to pass to any method like `initWithURL`

Hope this gets you on track to fix your `initWithURL` issue.

For getting your web view to open when tapping on a cell, setup your `UIWebView` inside `didSelectRowAtIndex`, and then push the controller that contains the `UIWebView`  onto your nav controller.

Comment: You are correct, and thanks for the tip about naming.  Still new to this.  

I understand now, but I still can't get didSelectRow to trigger a new screen.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to a tutorial which might help you.

Comment: Thanks, that helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

O.k

1. you can open any view controller you want when the user taps on a cell. BTW you can even do any thing you want.
2. `DetailTableViewController *detail = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];` as I said can be anything that you want, **BUT:**
3. As far as I know you can not subclass a UIWebView (You can but apple recommends not to).
4. Instead you should create a UIViewController and add a UIWebView as it's view or subview.
5. Then in your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` init this viewController and pass the url as a parameter to the viewController.
6. In `viewDidAppear` open the URL in your webView.

Good Luck

Comment: trying to use `webViewController *webView = [[webViewController alloc] initWithURL:@"http://www.google.com"];`

But I'm getting an error, no visible @interface for initWithURL